# Configure closed generic types for Unity constructor injection

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container, .net-4.5

I have the following set of types:
`IQueryProvider` interface:

```
public interface IQueryProvider<TEntity, TEntityKey>
```

and an implementation with one generic parameter added:

```
public class EFQueryProvider<TContext, TEntity, TEntityKey> : IQueryProvider<TEntity, TEntityKey>.
```

Further, there are concrete repositories, which incapsulate generic QueryProvider. For example:

```
UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
   private IQueryProvider<User, int> _provider;

   public UserRepository(IQueryProvider<User, int> provider)
   {
       _provider = provider;
   }
}
```

I'm trying to resolve the constructor parameter using Unity configuration:

```
<register type="IUserRepository" mapTo="ConcreteUserRepository">
  <constructor>
     <param ... What should be here??? />
  <constructor>
</register>
```

How can I pass an instance of closed generic type to the constructor (So that an instance of `EFQueryProvider<MySampleContext, User, int>` would be passed to the constructor? I need to do this per Repository registration, cause ArticlesRepository, for example can need another Context.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please tag this question with the language you are using. Is it [tag:.net]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution by myself.
The config should look like:

```
<register name="myQueryProvider" type="MyLib.IQueryProvider[[User, MyEntityLib], int], MyAnotherLib" mapTo="MyLib.EFQueryProvider[[MyContext, MyEFLib], [User, MyEntityLib], int], MyEFLib" />
```

and Repository registration:

```
<register type="IUserRepository" mapTo="UserRepository">
        <constructor>
          <param name="queryProvider">
            <dependency name="myQueryProvider" />
          </param>
        </constructor>
      </register>
```